# Python: How can I search a text file for a string input by the user that contains an integer?

Tags: python, search

This is an example of what is on the text file that I am searching:

```
15 - Project `enter code here`Name
APP_IDENTIFIER=ie.example.example
DISPLAY_NAME=Mobile Banking
BUNDLE_VERSION=1.1.1
HEADER_COLOR=#72453h
ANDROID_VERSION_CODE=3


20 - Project Name
APP_IDENTIFIER=ie.exampleTwo.exampleTwp
DISPLAY_NAME=More Mobile Banking
BUNDLE_VERSION=1.2.3
HEADER_COLOR=#23456g
ANDROID_VERSION_CODE=6
```

If, for example, the user types in 15, I want python to copy the following info:

```
ie.example.example
Mobile Banking
1.1.1
#72453h
3
```

because I need to copy it into a different text file.

I get the user to input a project number (in this example the project numbers are 15 & 20) and then I need the program to copy the app_identifier, display_name, bundle_version and android_version of the project relating to the number that the user input.

How do I get python to search the text file for the number input by the user and only take the needed information from the lines directly below that specific project?

I have a whole program written but this is just one section of it.
I don't really have any code yet to find and copy the specific information I need.
Here is code i have to search for the project ID

```
while True: 
    CUID = int(input("\nPlease choose an option:\n"))
    if (CUID) == 0:
        print ("Project one")
        break
    elif (CUID) == 15:
        print ("Project two")
        break
    elif (CUID) == 89:
        print ("Project three")
        break
    else:
        print ("Incorrect input")
```

The solution thanks to Conor:

```
projectFile = open("C:/mobileBuildSettings.txt" , "r")
for line in projectFile:
    CUID = str(CUID)
    if CUID + " - " in line:
            appIdentifier = next(projectFile).split("=")[1]
            displayName = next(projectFile).split("=")[1]
            bundleVersion = next(projectFile).split("=")[1]
            next(projectFile)
            androidVersionCode = next(projectFile).split("=")[1]

            print (appIdentifier, displayName, bundleVersion,     androidVersionCode)

            break
```

Comment: @cdarke this is what I have for user input:

    #User input to chose a CUDID
    while True: 
        CUID = int(input("\nPlease choose an option:\n"))
        if (CUID) == 0:
            print ("My CU")
            break
        elif (CUID) == 15:
            print ("Your CU")
            break
        elif (CUID) == 89:
            print ("Their CU")
            break
        else:
            print ("Incorrect input")



I am new to stackoverflow, I don't know how to add code to comments properly

Comment: Your code would fit much better as an addition to your main question. Click the `edit` link at the bottom of your question, then add and edit your code.

Comment: What information you want to get here? I mean what is needed information? If you want to get values there is a simple solution. But your code does nothing except comparing the Project Number.

Comment: @hzleonardo I just added in what I need specifically (check above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
projectfile = open("projects", "r")
    for line in projectfile:
        if CUID in line:
            appIdentifier = next(projectfile).split("=")[1]
            displayName = next(projectfile).split("=")[1]
            bundleVersion = next(projectfile).split("=")[1]
            next(projectfile)
            androidVersionCode = next(projectfile).split("=")[1]

            # Do whatever with the 4 values here, call function etc.

            break
```

Then do with appIdentifier, displayName, bundleVersion & androidVersionCode what you will, they will return just the values after the '='.

Although I would recommend against generically searching for an integer, what if the integer is also in the bundle or android version?

Comment: Brilliant thanks so much Conor you were a great help! I've added into my main questoin your code which I changed a bit to do what I needed. So delighted thank you :D

Comment: I added the following code to get python to find the int I need and not some random one that might be in the bundle or android version! Hopefully it will do the job, I'll test it in a minute.

 if CUID + " - " in line:

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to list all individual numbers in a long `if..else` list. You can use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to check if a line starts with *any* digit. If it does, check if it matches the number you are looking for, and if it does not, skip the following lines until you reach your blank line separator.

As soon as you have the data you are looking for, you can use a regular expression again to locate the `=`, or simply use `.find`:

```
import re
numberToLookFor = '18'
with open("project.txt") as file:
    while True:
        line = file.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
        if re.match('^'+numberToLookFor+r'\b', line):
            while line and line != '':
                if line.find('='):
                    print line[line.find('=')+1:]
                line = file.readline().rstrip('\r\n')
        else:
            while line and line != '':
                line = file.readline().rstrip('\r\n')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
while True: 
    CUID = int(input("\nPlease choose an option:\n"))
    if (CUID) == 0:
       appid = value.split("APP_IDENTIFIER=")[1] # get the value after "APP_IDENTIFIER="
       print appid
       output >>> ie.example.example
```

You can apply the same code for all values there, just change the title before "=".

Get the whole line from text then get only the value after "=" with this code for result output.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!